# Passing data to components which are deactivated mode in vuejs

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I have multiple dynamically instantiated components which I am storing in an array
I am keeping the components in`<keep-alive></keep-alive>` so that they are not destroyed. I am showing the components as the need from

`<component :is="selectedComponent"></component>`.

Now if an event/condition occurs I need to pass an event by props or through event emitter to all the components which are in the deactivated state and activated state or to all the component in the array of components.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass data as props when using dynamic components

**Parent:**

```
...
<component :is="selectedComponent" yourprop="{ key: value }"></component>
...
```

**Child:**

```
...
export default {
  ...
  props: ['yourprop']
  ... 
}
...
```

For further information, you should read [here](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#v-bind)

Comment: But this does not work for the components which are in the deactivated state. it only works for the component which is current active